# Execute task after several async connections

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous

I have several concurrent asynchronous network operations, and want to be notified after all of them finished receiving the data.

The current thread shall not be blocked, synchronous connections aren't an option, and all operations shall be executed concurrently.

How can I achieve that? Or is it more performant to execute all network operations successively, particularly looking at mobile devices?

Comment: It will be easier for us if we can have some code to help you. Otherwise, I dealt with it several time and on the last completion block I run a notification from NSNotificationCenter or a delegate method implemented by the class which implement that which is doing asynchronous network operations

Comment: Code? What code? You can apply this to every modern programming language. What do you want? Java, Objective-C, C, C++, Python?

Comment: Your question is tagged in Objective-c, so I excepted a snippet code in there you would like call a method after the execution of some asynchronous network operations.

Comment: Imagine three or more `+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`.

Comment: So what is your problem? you have a completionHandler..in that block you know that 1 request has finished..

Comment: I'am not dumb. I know when one is finished. If I want to track three (or even more) I need a huge amount of variables. There must be a better way.

Comment: Is that your queries are nested in completion block ?

Comment: @JeanLebrument Nope, they're executed concurrently.