# Keeping track of several AsyncTasks in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My app spawns an `AsyncTask` which does a potentially time-consuming calculation.  So, the `AsyncTask` unhides a progress bar:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

(`progressBar` is initialized in the constructor.)  The progress bar is re-hidden after the calculation is finished:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // ...
}
```

I wanted to change the app so that several of these tasks run at once (hooray for multiple cores!).  The problem is that with this design, the first `AsyncTask` hides the progress bar, even though there are several other tasks still running.

What's the best way to have only the last task perform an action, or to perform an action when all the tasks I called are done?

Comment: What a funny coincident, I happen to have the same [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461113/execute-task-after-several-async-connections).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a simple counter incremented in onPreExecute and decremented on onPostExecute. If counter reaches 0 then hide the progress bar.

Comment: Just a static variable in the class?  What if I call the tasks with different progress bars?

Comment: In my case I use the indeterminate progress bar in the action bar, so all network activity is indicated by the one progress bar. A non-static integer in the Activity keeps a record of the pending tasks count.

Comment: If you're using different progress bars (in different parts of your layout) then I'm sure you will want to show and hide them independently and maintain a different counter for each one.

Comment: I made the counter into a class that has `.increment()` and `.decrement()` methods that automatically unhide and hide the progress bar.